# OfflineAudioContext - adding gain to multiple channels

Tags: webkitaudiocontext

I am trying to manipulate gain on individual buffers in an OfflineAudioText.

ac and data are previously determined after loading it in

```
 var source = ac.createBufferSource();
 source.buffer = data;
 var splitter = ac.createChannelSplitter(2);
 source.connect(splitter);
 var merger = ac.createChannelMerger(2);

 var gainNode = ac.createGain();
 gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;

 splitter.connect(gainNode, 0);
 splitter.connect(gainNode, 1);
 gainNode.connect(merger, 0, 1);
//error occurs here
 gainNode.connect(merger, 1, 0);

 var dest = ac.createMediaStreamDestination();
 merger.connect(dest);
```

Error: Failed to execute 'connect' on 'AudioNode': output index (1) exceeds number of outputs (1)

Answer (score 0):

I was not assigning the input correctly:

splitter.connect(gainNode, 0);
splitter.connect(gainNode, 1);

gainNode.connect(merger, 0, 0);
gainNode.connect(merger, 0, 1);